# Knockout.js click binding with parameters

Tags: knockout.js

I have this little ViewModel:

```
function BooksViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.books = ko.observableArray(library);

    self.findByLanguage = function(lang) {
        self.books = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(library, function(book) { 
                return book.language() === lang; 
            });
        });
    };
}
```

The findByLanguage method filters the array by language. In the view, im tryign to implement that like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="click: findByLanguage('C')">C</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="click: findByLanguage('Cpp')">C++</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm attemping to reuse the function by calling the language parameter from there. But if I pass a function with parenthesis on data-bind it automatically gets called.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be interested in a slightly different approach that add extra fields into your View Model.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/RN9Dw/

By adding `languages` into the View Model you can use Knockout to render the menu and the `click` binding will automatically pass the language that was clicked to the handler function.  Additionally, adding `selectedLanguage` as an observable allows the `books` computed to change when you select or clear a language.

### HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: languages">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $root.filterByLanguage"></a></li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: showAll">Show All</button>

<div data-bind="foreach: books">
    <p><span data-bind="text: name"></span>, <span data-bind="text: language"></span></p>
</div>​
```

### JS

```
function BooksViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.languages = ko.observableArray(['C', 'C++']);
    self.selectedLanguage = ko.observable();
    self.library = [{name: 'Book A', language: 'C'}, {name: 'Book B', language: 'C++'}]; 
    self.books = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.library, function(book) { 
          return self.selectedLanguage() == null ||
              book.language === self.selectedLanguage(); 
          })
    });

    self.showAll = function() {
        self.selectedLanguage(null);
    }
    self.filterByLanguage = function(lang) {
        self.selectedLanguage(lang);
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new BooksViewModel());
```

​

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to wrap this in a function that executes only on click, like:

```
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="click: function () {findByLanguage('C')}">
```

Alternatively, you can use the bind context should do the trick.

```
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="click: findByLanguage.bind('C')">
```

[Here is an example of the click binding using JS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uFyaP/1/)](http://jsfiddle.net/uFyaP/1/)

Comment: It doen't gets called myfriend

Comment: I've attached a JS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uFyaP/1/) It does seem to work, but what I did find along the way was that it wasn't working at first because I left in `self.books = ko.observableArray(library);` in which library was not defined.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed in another context. It's small, readable and elegant. Btw: it works the same way on submit bindings. More infos on the [Knockout-Doku](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

Comment: The JSFiddle example above does not have .bind scenario. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Ly2v90mn/

Comment: Very nice... this applies to not just knockout but many other plugins as well to avoid having a function being called upon its definition. I WILL PRAISE THIS SOLUTION FOR THE REST OF MY LIFE

Comment: Very nice hack. I think this is a hack, rather than implementing some kind of nice thing like mentioned in the accepted answer. Don't know what would have happened without this. Probably toiling away into the night.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is old, but in case someone is interested, according to [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html), first parameter should be a viewModel, then it works as expected.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="click: findByLanguage.bind($data, 'C')">C</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="click: findByLanguage.bind($data, 'Cpp')">C++</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ur solution will call findByLanguage on load before on click. U have either wrap around a function or use bind

Comment: This answer is correct. The bind will not cause the function to be called, Ravi, and the addition of the $data parameter was the only way I could get my parameters to line up.

Comment: @JimWindram, I have updated the answer after Ravi's comment. I overlooked the `.bind` invocation in my original answer.